# How can I display 3 lines of text at a time onto 1 line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a log file that displays data 3 lines at a time.
Like this:

```
1 data   
2 data   
3 data   
1 data   
2 data   
3 data   
1 data   
2 data   
3 data
```

I'd like to take each 3 lines and display them on 1 line like this:

```
1 data 2 data 3 data  
1 data 2 data 3 data  
1 data 2 data 3 data
```

I'd like to be able to cat this file and then pipe it through a command(s) that will do this for me. I suspect sed or awk are a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be able to use `paste`:

```
$ paste - - - <data.txt
1 data      2 data      3 data   
1 data      2 data      3 data   
1 data      2 data      3 data
```

Comment: Paste is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ / unless $. % 3 == 0' file 
1 data    2 data    3 data   
1 data    2 data    3 data   
1 data    2 data    3 data
```

Answer (score 2):

Or also `sed` by "N"omming two lines and then nixing the newlines in the resulting buffer.

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: Nomming. Love it.